# log4j rotate and compress files

Tags: log4j

Is it possible to rotate and compress files with log4j with the logging.yml configuration?

It looks like there are two policies at the moment - TimeBased (which compress files, but not based on size) and SizeBased (which doesn't compress files), but I can't see option how to configure rotation and compression at the same time. For example, "rotate files bigger than 10M and compress them".

If anyone have logging.yml example, I would appreciate a lot.

This is logging.yml at the moment but it doesn't rotate based on size and doesn't compress:

```
rootLogger: DEBUG, console, file
log4j.appender: org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender

file:
   type: org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
   file: ${path.logs}/${cluster.name}.log
   rollingPolicy: org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
   rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern: ${path.logs}/${cluster.name}.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz
   trigeringPolicy: org.apache.log4j.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
   trigeringPolicy.MaxFileSize: 10M
   trigeringPolicy.MaxBackupIndex: 5
   layout:
     type: pattern
     conversionPattern: "%d{ISO8601}[%-5p][%-25c] %m%n"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.
Worked with 2.17 version.

> log4j.rootLogger=INFO, loggerId
>   log4j.appender.loggerId=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
>   log4j.appender.loggerId.rollingPolicy.maxIndex=5
>   log4j.appender.loggerId.triggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
>   log4j.appender.loggerId.triggeringPolicy.MaxFileSize=10000000
>   log4j.appender.loggerId.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=worker-%i.log.gz
>   log4j.appender.loggerId.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=worker.log
>   log4j.appender.loggerId.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>   log4j.appender.loggerId.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p (%F:%L)
>   - %m%n